# Android fitness REST API missing data points

Tags: google-api, google-fit

Here is what I am doing:
I installed Google Fit app on my phone and collected some fitness data:
[image: screenshot from the app]

Then I wen to [OAuth 2.0 Playground](https://developers.google.com/) and tried to read that data with a REST request:

Method: POST
URI: https://www.googleapis.com/fitness/v1/users/me/dataset:aggregate
BODY:

```
{
  "aggregateBy": [{
    "dataTypeName": "com.google.calories",
    "dataSourceId": "derived:com.google.calories.bmr:com.google.android.gms:merged"
  }],
  "bucketByTime": { "durationMillis": 86400000 },
  "startTimeMillis": 1547232519000,
  "endTimeMillis": 1547837319000
}
```

What I expected to get:
7 datasets for 7 following days with one datapoint in each. Expected values are as follows:

- 12th January: 0
- 13th January: 0
- 14th January: 1688
- 15th January: 1934
- 16th January: 844
- 17th January: 0
- 18th January: 857

What I actually get is:

All days but 14th (with different start and end time of course):

```
{
  "startTimeMillis": "1547578119000", 
  "endTimeMillis": "1547664519000", 
  "dataset": [
    {
      "dataSourceId":"derived:com.google.calories.bmr.summary:com.google.android.gms:aggregated", 
      "point": []
    }
  ]
},
```

14th January:

```
{
  "startTimeMillis": "1547491719000", 
  "endTimeMillis": "1547578119000", 
  "dataset": [
    {
      "dataSourceId": "derived:com.google.calories.bmr.summary:com.google.android.gms:aggregated", 
      "point": [
        {
          "startTimeNanos": "1547500395267000000", 
          "originDataSourceId": "derived:com.google.calories.bmr:com.google.android.gms:from_height&weight", 
          "endTimeNanos": "1547500402445000000", 
          "value": [
            {
              "mapVal": [], 
              "fpVal": 1688.25
            }, 
            {
              "mapVal": [], 
              "fpVal": 1688.25
            }, 
            {
              "mapVal": [], 
              "fpVal": 1688.25
            }
          ], 
          "dataTypeName": "com.google.calories.bmr.summary"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
},
```

Does anyone know why I don't get any value for most of the brackets while I do get value for one of them? And why is the value for 14th listed 3 times?

(Also I can't force these code blocks to format properly, apologies for that)

Comment: Can you doing it with hour-aligned bins? For instance, your start timestamp is 2019-01-11T18:48:39+00:00 - could you try with 2019-01-11T18:00:00+00:00 (or 01:00:00 - I'm assuming that you're in Central European Time)? (It shouldn't be so broken as to not accept arbitrary times; but I'm just trying to rule that out as a reason)

Comment: I just tried it and results are the same. I also tried setting the start and end time to 00:00 and changing the bracket size to 3600000 (1 hour) and none of this worked.

Answer (score 0):

PUT THE CURRENT DATE AND TIME
1 Nov 2019: 1572586200 so the "startTimeMillis": "1572586200000"
8 Nov 2019: 1573191000 so the "endTimeMillis": "1573191000000"

put these 2 in the request body and it should work.

Comment: Hi Amit, welcome to SO. You should try to format your answers using backticks to encompass code (`` to yield something like `endTimeMillis`).

Comment: What you suggest is simply changing the time period that the data is being returned from. I can't see how it's related to the issue